# How can I reuse/import code in vtl appsync resolvers?

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl

I want to avoid duplication of certain declarations in my vtl templates and share them between vtl resolvers.

Let's say I have a sample dict in **mapping_templates/shared.vtl**

```
#set($sample_mappings = {
    "KEY1": "VALUE1",
    "KEY2": "KEY2"
})
```

which I want to use in **mapping_templates/sample_request_mapping_template.vtl**, for example to do:

```
$sample_mappings.get("KEY1")
```

I tried the following with no success:

```
#parse("shared.vtl")
OR
#include("shared.vtl")

$sample_mappings.get("KEY1")
```

Really seems like a very basic feature, but I don't see it documented on aws' resolver guide, and I'm thinking this might not be supported as AppSync vtl doesn't even support all standard features of vtl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not supported currently.

I will +1 this request to the team on your behalf.

Comment: Hi, is it any news on this? It will be very useful if we could reuse code in vtl templates.

Answer (score 2):

We've used nested stacks to get some reuse out of our VTL code.

Nested stack template `../cfn/shared/vtl/template.yml`:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Vtl Functions

Parameters:
  VtlSomeCheckFunction:
    Type: String
    Default: |
      #***#
      #if($util.isNullOrBlank($ctx.args.input.someArg))
        $util.error("Some error occurred")
      #end
      #***#
...

Outputs:
  VtlSomeCheckFunction:
    Description: VtlSomeCheckFunction
    Value: !Ref VtlSomeCheckFunction
```

A stack using the nested VTL stack:

```yaml
Resources:
  VtlStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ../cfn/shared/vtl/template.yml
...
  MutationUpdateResolver:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      ...
      RequestMappingTemplate: !Join
        - ''
        - - !GetAtt VtlStack.Outputs.VtlSomeCheckFunction
          - |
            #***#
            #set($items = ...
            ...
```

Comment: this worked really well

Answer (score 1):

You could also use AWS Systems manager to retrieve the template from the parameter store.
Save the string in systems manager and reference it in your template.

To borrow from @ggriffin's solution and substitute the SSM value

```
  Resolver:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      ...
      RequestMappingTemplate: !Join
        - ''
        - - '{{resolve:ssm:/path/to/param}}'
          - |
            #***#
            #set($items = ...
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, I found a NodeJS template engine, [EJS](https://ejs.co/). It enables to insert one plain-text file into another. However, EJS itself only support to process a single file. I had to use [a cli](https://github.com/fnobi/ejs-cli) built on top of EJS which can handle a folder of VTL scripts recursively.

- Input:

```
# File: src/vtl/Query.query1.vtl
<%- include('level1/level1-scriptA.vtl'); %>
// perform query1.vtl
<%- include('level1/level1-scriptB.vtl'); %>
```

- Output:

```
# File: dist/vtl/Query.query1.vtl
// perform level2-script.vtl
// perform level1-scriptA.vtl
// perform query1.vtl
// perform level2-script.vtl
// perform level1-scriptB.vtl
```

Full example can be found [here](https://github.com/tmhung88/vtl-reusability)